# Web3j CLI generate file location

Tags: intellij-idea, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3-java

I'm using web3j CLI to generate java code. My command is as below (i'm in solidity folder currently):

```
 web3j generate solidity -b tempFiles/MasterDAO.bin -a tempFiles/MasterDAO.abi -o ../java -p org.web3j
```

And my file structure is as the graph shows.
[image]

The abi file and bin file is saved in tempFiles folder.
However, when I press enter, the web3j says that

```
Generating org.web3j.MasterDAO ... not a valid name:
```

I'm confusing what goes wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, the web3j does not support **event** and **emit** keywords, remove them  and it works fine.